# is there any way to call an outside class to the main class?

Tags: groovy

is there any way to call an outside class to the main class?

for example you have a main class named ***main.groovy*** and you have another class named ***myOtherClass.groovy*** how can you call the myOtherclass.groovy to main.groovy?

Comment: in java you just have to declare a variable for the outer class(e.g `code`myOtherClass class = new myOtherClass();`code`

Comment: Yes, try to do the same in Groovy and let know your results.

Comment: `code`package PinPayment

class RefundPut {
 
 
 public static void main (String [] args){
  
  //new RefundPut()
  Customers customer = new Customers()
 }
}
`code` and the error is `code`Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovyx/net/http/HttpResponseException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovyx/net/http/HttpResponseException
 at PinPayment.RefundPut.main(RefundPut.groovy:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException
 ... 1 more  `code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File sourceFile = new File("src/com/test/myOtherClass.groovy");
Class myOtherclass = new GroovyClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader()).parseClass(sourceFile);
    GroovyObject customer = (GroovyObject) customerService.newInstance();
```